# Multiple TV out from single Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, hdmi

I would like to present a digital art show using audio and video.
For this I was thinking of using 10 TV sets.

Is there a way that I could use my MacBook Pro to show either:

a) 10 separate videos (1 per TV screen)
or
b) a single video to all 10 screens

My MacBook Pro is less than a year old and has a single HDMI output.
Is there any software out there that could handle this?

Apologies if this sounds ludicrous. I am a complete novice!
Grateful for any advice / pointers.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

a) You can't output 10 different video signals on your single HDMI output. Besides limitation of the graphic card of your computer, that would also require generating/reading 10 different video streams from your computer. One possible option, depending on your project aim and structure, is to produce 1 hi definition video stream from your computer and use an external tool to tile/scale it in 10 different screens (something like http://www.ambery.com/2x2hdvgaviwa.html)

b) sending same video to all 10 screens only requires that you have a one input/ten outputs HDMI splitter (assuming your ten screens have a HDMI input).